# Why does Java App take less overall CPU when running multiple instances of app instead of one instance?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, cpu-usage

I've got a Java App running on Ubuntu, the app listens on a socket for incoming connections, and creates a new thread to process each connection.   The app receives incoming data on each connection processes the data, and sends the processed data back to the client.  Simple enough.

With only one instance of the application running and up to 70 simultaneous threads, the app will run up the CPU to over 150%.. and have trouble keeping up processing the incoming data.  This is running on a Dell 24 Core System.

Now if I create 3 instances of my application, and split the incoming data across the 3 instances on the same machine, the max overall cpu on the same machine may only reach 25%.

Question is why would one instance of the application use 6 times the amount of CPU that 3 instances on the same machine each processing one third of the amount of data use?

I'm not a linux guy, but can anyone recommend a tool to monitor system resources to try and figure out where the bottleneck is occurring? Any clues as to why 3 instances processing the same amount of data as 1 instance would use so much less overall system CPU?

Comment: I''ve never used, but [DTrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace) is a famous one to monitor system behavior.
There seems to be for linux, too. https://github.com/dtrace4linux/linux

Comment: 70 threads are unresponsive at 150% load on a 24 core machine?  There is something wrong in your program, some shared resource contention or something.

Answer (score 0):

In general this should not be the case. Maybe you are *reading the CPU usage wrong*. Try `top`, `htop`, `ps`, `vmstat` commands to see what's going on.

I could imagine one of the reasons for such behaviour - **resource contention**. If you have some sort of lock or a busy loop which manifests itself only on one instance (max connections, or max threads) then your system might not parallelize processing optimally and wait for resources. I suggest to connect something like `jconsole` to your java processes and see what's happening.

As a general recommendation check how many **threads** are available per JVM and if you are using them correctly. Maybe you don't have enough **memory** allocated to JVM so it's garbage collecting too often. If you use database ops then check for bottlenecks there too. **Profile** and find the place where it spends most of the time and compare 1 to 3 instances in terms of % of time spend in that function.